# Standard ML: Modify depth function for binary tree

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm given a depth function for a binary tree as follows:

```
fun depth Empty = 0
    | depth(Node(t_1, _ t_2)) = max(depth t_1, depth t_2) + 1;
```

Suppose I want to modify this depth function such that a single node will have depth 0 (as it is, a single node will have depth 1).  How would I go about doing this?

I was thinking:

```
fun depth Empty = 0
    | depth(Node(Empty, _, Empty)) = 0
    | depth(Node(t_1, _, t_2)) = max(depth t_1, depth t_2) + 1;
```

Does this look right?

Thanks,

bclayman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close, but not quite right.  `depth(Node(Node(Empty,1,Empty),2,Empty)` will recurse on the left subtree, which is a single node, so it will return `0`.  Then it will recurse on the right, which is empty, returning 0.  You will then take the max of 0 and 0, returning 1, which is probably not what you want.  Instead, you would have to match the empty case, and the singleton case as you have done, and for the default case, you will want to call the original version, that returns 1 for a single node.

Comment: the original version = the function I first gave?  Can I do this without writing a separate function?

Comment: Yes by original I meant the first function you gave.  The only way I can think of doing this with one function is to add an extra boolean parameter that determines if you have already performed an iteration.  If you end up in the single node case, and the boolean is false, then return 0, otherwise return 1.  In either case, there is kind of an awkward asymmetry.